# Mysql How to find the value that same inside the result of query

Tags: mysql

I have a query which is like below

```
SELECT user_id,user_task.task_id 
FROM user_task 
JOIN task ON user_task.task_id = task.task_id 
WHERE user_task.user_id IN (2,60,59)
```

Which return the result like this below

[image]

What I want now is only get the `task_id` that `user_id` (2,60,59) that having the same value which is `1` and eliminate all the record with `task_id` 2,3,4,5.

One more thing is the amount of value inside `IN()` is different every time.

How can I do it in single query?

Edit

Here I attach the `user_task` table and `task` table

User_task table

[image]

Task table

[image]

Comment: Have you checked my answer ? @ken

Comment: @your answer wrong bro..cause the table i show is the result,not a table..

Comment: so what result did you get ?

Comment: can you provide more table , like table user and  table task

Comment: ok..later I provide.

Comment: @Gagantous I attach the table involved as well

Comment: Have you checked my latest answer, it seems like my answer is what you're looking for...

Answer (score 0):

All you need is group by perhaps

```
 SELECT user_id,user_task.task_id 
    FROM user_task 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN task ON user_task.task_id = task.task_id 
    WHERE user_task.user_id IN (2,60,59) AND user_task.task_id = '1'
    GROUP BY user_task.user_id
```

**The Result**
[image]

Comment: I dont know the user_task.task_id ='1' in the 1st place